# How would I access the Windows Login (Authentication) API from a C++ Service Application?

Tags: windows, security, visual-c++, windows-services, windows-authentication

Let us imagine for a moment that I have a piece of hardware that can act as an authentication for a user on a given system. I want to write an application in C++ to run as a service, look for this device and if found log the appropriate user in. I believe I have found the API's I would need to use to perform the hardware and service portions of the application but am having a hard time nailing down a way to create a "real" user login. Is this possible? If so where would I look to find resources on accomplishing this? I think of it as being an analog to fingerprint scanner login type devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for the GINA ("Graphical Identification aNd Authentication) APIs. There is a good tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx).

Comment: Cheers. Does GINA work for you then? It doesn't exactly fit with your idea of a service polling your hardware- I think you have to wait for GINA to load your module when a user tries to login, *then* contact your hardware for authentication.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for an API to validate the credentials, here is one way..

```
Public Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As [String], 
ByVal lpszDomain As [String], ByVal lpszPassword As [String], _
ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean
```

Here is the full code ->  http://codingforpassion.blogspot.com/2011/07/windows-logon-api-for-net.html

Thanks,
Srikanth.V

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Srikanth! I *think* you misunderstood the question, he is asking about replacing Windows Logon... i.e. potentially replacing the password question after boot-up with a fingerprint scan or similar. Also note this question was asked over a year ago and an acceptable answer was found at the time...